# can raw contact ids of 2 contacts be same in android..?

Tags: android, android-contacts, rawcontactid

I know CONTACT_Id's are different. but are RAW_CONTACT_ID's are also unique for each contact..?

Answer (score 0):

RawContactID are unique but Contact ID can be same in case of Join.